# How to pick the records according to month in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get the records, if later then effective date. If I give 1, it should get records effective date between 2016-01-04 and 2016-03-04.

Sample data query:

```
select employeecode, basic, effectivedt 
from PaymentEarningDetails
```

Sample data output:

```
Employeecode    Basic   Effectivedt
------------------------------------
KT007           4545    2016-01-04
KT007           555     2016-03-04
```

Desired output - if input month is 1 and year 2016.

```
KT007           4545    2016-01-04
```

Query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    MONTH(effectivedt), EffectiveDt
FROM 
    PaymentEarningDetails
WHERE 
    Employeecode = 'KT007'
    AND MONTH(effectivedt) <= '2'
    AND YEAR(effectivedt) >= '2016'
ORDER BY 
    EffectiveDt DESC
```

Comment: `top 1` is not an input, it is a query to get the top item

Comment: is it correct or wrong.

Comment: Your question description isnt clear and doesnt match the query you wrote, try to rewrite it and provider a bigger example.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: It is correct. Or wrong. Actually I have no idea how from this - _"if i give 1 it should get records effective date between 2016-01-04 and 2016-03-04"_ - **"1"** is supposed to be related to such "between" expression.

Answer (score 0):

I'm understanding that you need everything in 01 month of 2016 year, Please try this.

```
SELECT 
    MONTH(effectivedt), EffectiveDt
FROM 
    PaymentEarningDetails
WHERE 
    Employeecode = 'KT007'
    AND MONTH(effectivedt) = 1
    AND YEAR(effectivedt) = 2016
ORDER BY 
    EffectiveDt DESC
```